# Can anybody provide any information about this equation? $2^2 = \left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^2 - \left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^2 $

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Can anybody provide me with any information about this fascinating equation?

$$2^2 = \left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^2 - \left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^2 $$

I have been told many different things:

1) It is a mathematical Identity.

2) It is not a mathematical identity (because it does not work for
    zero).

3) It is a special case of the difference of squares equation.

Can anybody give me any concrete facts? The reason i ask is because it's so interesting. For example:

We can link this equation with Pythagoras’s theorem, so that for each number (x) we have a corresponding right angled

triangle and each triangle has height (A) = 2, base (B) = x-1/x and hypotenuse (C) = x+1/x.

[image: triangle formation]

As you can see, we can also link it with Trigonometry.

[Triangle Formation Animation](https://gfycat.com/disfiguredevergreenchinesecrocodilelizard)

And because tangents to an arc are always reciprocals, we can use it to get the following equations:

[image: Tangent equations]

SO, why does an equation this interesting not have a name (or does it?) and why is it not more well known?

I have been playing around with the geometry of this equation for years and it has allowed me to create many tools to help visualize the symmetry of a number or angle, for example:

[Symmetry Animation](https://gfycat.com/selfreliantmealyfinnishspitz-geometry-patterns-circles-shapes-angles-maths)

We can also link this equation with the [metallic means](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3305144/the-origin-of-the-fibonacci-sequence-and-the-metallic-means-or-silver-means-als).

Does this equation work for zero?

Assuming that (x) is always >= 1 and that (1/x) is always <= 1.

[image: zero]

As you can see, these variables always cancel each other out. Substituting 1/x = 0 (zero) and x = ∞ (infinity).

[image: infinity zero]

Tangents to an arc are always reciprocals.

[image: Tangents to the arc]

Comment: Sorry, but this identity is not especially remarkable. With $x:=e^t$, is amounts to the hyperbolic relation $\cosh^2t-\sinh^2t=1$. It sometimes appears in changes of variables for integration.

Comment: This equation is indeed very pretty. But mathematics is full of pretty equations...

Comment: The formula can be converted back to Eulid's formula where $\space F(m,n)=F(m,1)\space$ and it generates the following:

\begin{align*}
F(2,1)&=(3,4,5),\qquad 
F(3,1)=(8,6,10),\\ 
F(4,1)&=(15,8,17),\quad 
F(5,1)=(24,10,26),\\ 
F(6,1)&=(35,12,37),\quad 
F(7,1)=(48,14,50),\\ 
F(8,1)&=(63,16,65),\quad 
F(9,1)=(80,18,82),\\ 
F(10,1)&=(99,20,101),\quad
\cdots
\end{align*}

These are not your results and, here, every other triple is imprimitive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The identity $$4xy=(x+y)^2-(x-y)^2$$ can be used to show that if two numbers have a fixed sum, their product is greatest when they are equal, as well as the AM/GM inequality for two numbers. It is well known and useful.

If we fix $xy=C$ then the identity $4C=(x+\frac Cx)^2-(x-\frac Cx)^2$ applies where all the terms are defined ie for $x\neq 0$ (note that $C$ need not be positive here).

Answer (score 3):

Using the formula $$a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$$ we get
$$(x+\frac{1}{x}+x-\frac{1}{x})(x+\frac{1}{x}-x+\frac{1}{x})=2x\cdot \frac{2}{x}=4$$ if $$x\neq 0$$

Comment: I think it is quite evident that the OP already knows this, so I'm not quite sure what the point of this answer is.