# The origin of the Fibonacci sequence and the metallic means or silver means (also ratios or constants)

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry, trigonometry, ratio

Is this equation the origin of the **metallic means** or silver means? (also ratios or constants)

$ 2^2=(x+1/x)^2−(x−1/x)^2 $

As discussed in my previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3292114/can-anybody-provide-any-information-about-this-equation), we can link this equation with Pythagoras’s theorem, so that for each number (x) we have a corresponding right angled.

[image: cosmic triangles]

If **B** = 1, then **C** = √5 (Square root of 5), and because the following is true, we can calculate **x**:

$ 2(1/x) = C-B $

and,

$ 2(x) = C+B $

Which gives us these two equations :

[image: two equations]

Which we can combine into one equation :

[image: equation]

If we do the same for **B** = 1-9, we get the following:

[image: metallic means]

Each of these has a corresponding sequence of numbers, as you can see the first and second sequences are called Fibonacci and the Pell sequence. These sequences are known as the [metallic means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metallic_mean) or silver means.

As you can see below, as these sequences approach infinity, the ratio of the last two consecutive numbers tends towards the number (x).

[image: sequences]

As you can see below, as these sequences approach zero, the ratio of the last two consecutive numbers tends towards the number (1/x).

[image: sequnese2]

Why are the sequences above not mentioned on the Wikipedia page [metallic means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metallic_mean)? Including zero, we get these simplified equations:

[image: number 4]

Is this equation the origin of the **metallic means** ? And if so, why is it not on the wiki page? Can anybody help or provide more information?

$ 2^2=(x+1/x)^2−(x−1/x)^2 $

It is assumed that (x) is always ≥ 1 and the (1/x) is always ≤ 1.