# Is there a well known link between the 345 triangle and the metallic means (1,2) and sequences (Fibonacci, Pell)?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

Is there a well known link between the 345 triangle and the metallic means (1,2) and sequences (Fibonacci, Pell)?

The (gold) triangle is related to the 345 (blue) triangle.  (±) method is based on this [equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3292114/can-anybody-provide-any-information-about-this-equation-22-leftx-frac1).

[image]

I've noticed recently that every triangle has 2 associated  numbers (y1 and y2). The 345 triangle  (2 and 3) as shown below:

[image]

Examples and numbers.

[image]

The metallic means 1 and 4 are based on the same (gold) triangle. Metallic means (1-5)

[image]

Metallic means (1-10) and beyond.

[image]

My gut tells me that there is a link between (Fibonacci, Lucas, Pell and maybe Binet's formulas, pythagorean triples)

[image]

If anybody can help me understand this relationship that would be very helpful. Am i missing something?

Comment: You've provided a ton of information but there's no real coherence to it. Like, there are a ton of numbers here, and some pretty diagrams, but not nearly enough labels. Your few short sentences of explanation don't really explain much at all. Can you give a clearer, cleaner summary? And, I suppose, what sort of link you think there is, so that we might actually provide help?

Comment: Thank you for responding. Metallic means 1 (Fibonacci) and 4 are both linked to the yellow (phi) triangle. The yellow triangle is linked to the blue 345 triangle. And the 345 triple is linked to the metallic mean 2 (pell) and i was wondering if anybody could help me understand these links. I there a link between pell and Fibonacci and the pythag triple (345)?

Answer (score 0):

There is one Pythagorean Triangle for each Metallic Mean. Triangle 3-4-5 represents Golden Ratio, as well as 4th and 6th Metallic Ratios.
https://youtu.be/LFW1saNOp20

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).